# sorting humanized size file and directory

Tags: linux, sorting, tree

command used is `tree -sifh . | sort -k2 -rh` and outputs is:

```
[  27]  ./ClientPanel/Taxonomy -> /HolismPanel/Taxonomy/User/
[  27]  ./ClientPanel/Contacts -> /HolismPanel/Contacts/User/
[  27]  ./ClientApi/Controllers/Modules -> /HolismApi/Modules/Api/User
[  27]  ./ClientApi/Controllers/Brands -> /HolismApi/Brands/Api/Admin
[  26]  ./SiteApi/SettingsOverride.json
[  26]  ./ClientPanel/Pricing -> /HolismPanel/Pricing/User/
[  26]  ./ClientPanel/Brands -> /HolismPanel/Brands/Admin/
[  26]  ./ClientApi/Controllers/Media -> /HolismApi/Media/Api/User/
[  24]  ./ClientPanel/Units -> /HolismPanel/Units/User/
[  24]  ./ClientPanel/Media -> /HolismPanel/Media/User/
[  22]  ./ClientPanel/Seo -> /HolismPanel/Seo/User/
[  19]  ./SiteApi/Progra
[3.4K]  ./Products/Api/Api/Site/ProductController.cs
[1.6K]  ./Clients/Site/Component/ManagementActiveCategory.jsx
[1.2K]  ./Clients/Api/Models/Views/ClientView.cs
[1.1K]  ./Products/Panel/Localization/Ru.json
[1.0K]  ./Products/Api/Database.json
101 directories, 199 files
[1004]  ./Products/Panel/Localization/Fa.json
[   0]  ./Common/OriginalTheme
```

size file is humanized and byte size is bigger than K Size, but in real world it's not accurate,
How to write sort section, kB size be ranked ahead of byte size?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I would do `du -h | sort -h`. Odd to use tree that way.

Comment: @KamilCuk
du outputs are **disk space is used **  but **ls** or **tree**  size of the file

Comment: Use `du --apparent-size` or just `du -b`

Comment: @KamilCuk `ls lh` result with `du -b` and `du --apparent-size` diffrent!